# Passing this to setTimeout function causes Uncaught TypeError: this.empty is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, settimeout

I'm trying to implement a copy to clipboard button in my application, but I am unable to update the button text using the `setTimeout` method. When I click on the button, I get the following error in the console

```
jquery-1.12.4.js:6375 Uncaught TypeError: this.empty is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (jquery-1.12.4.js:6375)
    at access (jquery-1.12.4.js:4399)
    at HTMLButtonElement.html (jquery-1.12.4.js:6338)
    at access (jquery-1.12.4.js:4416)
    at jQuery.fn.init.html (jquery-1.12.4.js:6338)
    at scripts.js:126
```

This is my code so far.

**My code:**

```js
$('button.copy-to-clipboard').on('click', function() {
  element = $(this).prev('.copy-text')[0];
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var range = document.createRange();
  var default_html = $(this).html;
  var that = this;
  range.selectNodeContents(element);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    if (successful) {
      $(that).addClass("copied");
      $(that).html("Copied");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).removeClass("copied");
        $(that).html(default_html);
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      $(that).addClass("copy-error");
      $(that).html("Unable to copy");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).removeClass("copy-error");
        $(that).html(default_html);
      }, 2000);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    $(this).html(err);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="copy-container"><span class="copy-text">6145555555</span><button class="copy-to-clipboard">Copy</button></span>
```

When you are answering please take into account that I am not a frontend developer. I am completely new to the nuances of JavaScript and jQuery!

Comment: It's a typo. :-) `var default_html = $(this).html;` should have `()` after `html`: `var default_html = $(this).html();`